# Could physically simulating neural structure on a fundamental level yield superior results to machine learning algorithms?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

My curiosity is merely of whether (in a future where we have computers with the processing power of the human brain) it's possible that actually simulating a neural network's physical *behavior* on the most fundamental level might be more effective than using algorithms to reach the same result.

I'm hoping for an answer which argues this topic on a purely fundamental level.

---

Is it likely (or not) that we might achieve a superior (more efficient, more intelligent, more dynamic) result by simulating the advanced behavior of neural interaction (the neuro-activity patterns the brain experiences to form emotions, develop conclusions, processes sensory data, establish and/or revisit memories, etc) than we can reach by using shortcuts (advanced machine learning algorithms, etc)?

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting question. Although I have not a single little bit of expertise in this area, I do have some references you may want to read. First is a paper by [Merz and Fromherz (2005)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229444024_Silicon_Chip_Interfaced_with_a_Geometrically_Defined_Net_of_Snail_Neurons) where they grew snail neurons on a silicon chip. [Pfister et al (2007)](http://europepmc.org/articles/PMC3979335) also tried to grow neurons to allow interfacing between neurons and machine (for neural prosthesis e.g.). There is thus definitely a field of research that believe neural interfacing may be better than mechanical and algorithmic networks.

There has been 10 years worth of research since these papers so I bet there are some advancements that may give you a more definitive answer than mine.